# Typescript strict mode error, declared type is missing properties

Tags: typescript

I have a code which works fine without typescript strict mode, no type error, but when strict mode is turn on, I get the next type error:

> Type 'Common' is missing the following properties from type
> 'Employee': name, position, department.

Example of code:

```
                interface Common {
                  id: string
                }

//ChildComponent.tsx
                
                type argType = Common | (Common & Record<string, unknown>)
    
    
                
                interface ChildComponentProps {
                  renderFun: (item: argType) => React.ReactNode
                    
                }
                
                const ChildComponent: FC<ChildComponentProps> = (props) => {
                  do something...
                }
    
    //ParentComponent.tsx
                
                interface Employee extends Common {
                  name: string;
                  position: string;
                  department: string;
                }
                
                const ParentComponent = () => {
                  return
                    <>
                      <ChildeComponent
                       renderFun={(item: Employee) => <>render something...</>} //here I get a type error
                      />
                    </>
                }
```

Link for other example [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2n0mQbwFgAoZM5YAEwC5kBnMKUAcwG4SBfEksATwAcUcKMwAqAlAF40WHHgA%20yABQZsuZADJkAJQgJ0USgB4GTEMwA0yAK4gA1iHQB3EAD4AlO2IlQkWIhRUAAtgABtKVX5cCHAABSh0fjoCEnJkKBjKaAAxW1olYEhMWmExCXdkSVcdCEQwADpdOoA5dCyvLm9ifRAGNBDwyOjwSuV%20BKTaYLCIrCiQGLB4xLoKqpTScgywayg8I1cjAHpXDq8fcGh4JGQAUUx%20UPReCBQIAA9IEEpk1TkNtIgOCYCC0UwsLxpKJ0QrAXBgxgQ1LkLL8YRgEHgBFmNicbjdXB9WLCRZDBYjaRKNbVIibMjbXZ4JTItJkA4s1lpIzTQZzYZgDmczkZb45WySfAFIq0e6PZ6vanIA4irJQehYCBgELmeq646uDjII5HILQFAASWQzE1yDgeD4gmQ0ASUEFQpObrZHrpyE8nHOxF8VwCyAAIhAAG7AG4fL4-GRqPC0wHA0H0RHmSHkaGw%20HpnFZsio9GYsDYpHETokHp9ADyWugxJFYDJi1GVMqNI5DL2yk9Stc-a5PNmD35Q6FKrFIAlUogxTDkejEEVysy0HVIK1LF19X1huNpoyyEt1rAtvtEidUBdE7I3qFSof5D9la8QA)

I use ChildeComponent in different places and property renderFunc gets different types of arguments, not only type Employee. In all places, all types of received arguments of property renderFun extends Common type. Please, help me to resolve this type error.

Answer (score 0):

In your definition, the compiler has no way to ensure that the parameter of `renderFun` will be `Employe` and not another subtype of `Common`/`argType`

One solution could be to make `ChildComponentProps` generic :

```
interface ChildComponentProps<T extends Common>{
  renderFun: (item: T) => React.ReactNode;
}

const ChildeComponent: React.FC<ChildComponentProps<Employee>> = (props) => {
  return <div></div>;
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
  return  <ChildeComponent
    renderFun={(item: Employee) => <div></div>} // ok
  />;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUKJLOQHQD0qMAngDZY2uVKlqNGwAHYwsUAnixwAwiRARJcAN6M4cYABMAXHG5QpAc3oMAvuIa8wi5FHMAVHo7gBeZavVwAMkwsXGh9AB5TCwAaOABXSQBrSQgAd0kAPisJaVl5XEUlAAtgPn0VcHUsaQAFYjBUcNc4LAAPGUl9dAq1TO0GXUpO2QAxBOMACmAZEGNXAEpvDOC8GDZsVYA5CH0sK1sGRlDJbmUSsqwKyElqmGMN-DYRpXDi0vKSa9u6iAbwgFFwHwIDwsFgMssfBMwPVUIsvMt%20oMsDA4lANOF9MAAG4ZcIcLG4-bZJi5OQKOCAsDA0GKNodLooFzuTxIuCSZAgLDGKKSSw6OCQVDTYDqHkwMx8qy6XZgZwwLnScWS-k2OzHU41Zy3K5VaTeOATeGIgWUVHo3Svc67XU3aQC5HDKBjSReTRTGbGKk0sHGuCYnF4gmB6xwDgcIqyRQASTg5hRKA0DjpUGIUAFHCyjGsJLaLHgu3kcT4hAS%20FFGgAgmAwEatKaUWiNBMHf7CRlW5aigBGDIACSwfGBcAAyjA8IkAEJ8aYALwAhPiex2Bro1%20EwBkx-KWliYBY4DAICYwSYSIoQMhzMBcHAisga9U4IZ5vjN638e2BfN9owgA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think about this solution, but I have a lot of types, not only Employee, and I want to reuse ChildeComponent in other places and in this case I will stack with the same problem. Maybe you know, how to pass specific type to ChildeComponent in JSX, like this <ChildeComponent<PropsType> />, do you? Or generic type for all cases?